# Why does my HP printer think it is jammed, when the printer is not jammed?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, paper

I have a strange problem with my HP F2480 printer. The printer always thinks it is jammed. It starts completely normally, and when it gets halfway down the page all the light start flashing, which is a fatal error according to HP.

However I can press the power button and recover, and HP says it is jammed. However the printer pushes the paper through normally. I printed a diagnostic page successfully, but no matter what I print from it thinks its jammed.

I have not overloaded the paper tray or anything. This has been completely random. The last thing that I printed was yesterday. I did not turn off the printer or anything. (I never turn it off!)

Is it time for a new printer?

Comment: It sounds like the printer has seen better days.

Comment: If it's under warranty get it checked by the retailer you bought it at. If it's not, then you could get into the guts and see if there's paper dust/scraps possibly blocking a sensor. It's probably not worth paying for it to be repaired.

Comment: I has a similar problem with an HP 8500.  After a lot of trying this and that with HP help staff, they decided to replace it (it was still under warranty).  If yours is not under warranty, time for a new one.

Comment: @Ramhound Tell me about it! It makes a cracking and grinding noise now when it recovers from the jam :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer - Programs cannot print on 2 pages per sheet. This seems like a driver problem. I would download the updated drivers from HP. Or just get a new printer. I'm just getting a new printer, as this one is on its last legs anyway.

Link: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=uk&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3811337